# location of drop down menu is left when div center aligned

Tags: drop-down-menu

I'm using a bit of javascript to create a dropdown that appears when an image is clicked. Currently the initial image is centered, but the drop down is appearing at the left of the frame... and I'm stumped. Help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
    <div align="center" class="dropdown">
    <img alt="Select Your District Here" onclick="showMenu()" src="images/buttons/select_district.png" style="width: 200px; height: 36px;" />
    <ul aria-labelledby="dLabel" class="dropdown-menu" id="district-dd2" onmouseout="hideMenu()" role="menu" style="display:none">
        <li>
            <a href="index.php?option=com_zoo&amp;view=frontpage&amp;layout=frontpage&amp;Itemid=512" title="Arbuckle">Arbuckle</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php?option=com_zoo&amp;view=frontpage&amp;layout=frontpage&amp;Itemid=514" title="Country Estates">Country Estates</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php?option=com_zoo&amp;view=frontpage&amp;layout=frontpage&amp;Itemid=542" title="Strawberry">Strawberry</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php?option=com_zoo&amp;view=frontpage&amp;layout=frontpage&amp;Itemid=525" title="Walnut Ranch">Walnut Ranch</a></li>
    </ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showMenu(){
   document.getElementById("district-dd2").style.display="block";
 }
 function hideMenu(){
   document.getElementById("district-dd2").style.display="none";
 }
</script></div>
```

Site can be seen here: http://www.waterutilitymanagementservices.com/deloro/water-districts.html

EDIT: CSS for dropdown-menu added. FYI, this site is using joomla beez template with bootstrap, with css heavily modified. the code below comes from bootstrap.css

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    clear: both;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

EDIT 2: More CSS - After scouring all my css files, it looks like all the references to dropdowns are in bootstrap.css. Rather than past all of them here (which would be long), i posted the CSS as a txt file here: http://www.waterutilitymanagementservices.com/boostrap.txt

Comment: Please, post css of `dropdown-menu`

Comment: Should have thought of that... sorry Nikita!

Comment: Forgot to mention `dropdown` from the div... Could you add is as well? It seems like the problem is in one of the parent styles. Creating just this block you posted gives me a fine centered alignment...

Comment: ...and the part you gave me is only for formatting of the links. It would help to see all of the css applicable to the html you posted.

Comment: Hmm, looks like there's one more problem too... I can hover/click successfully on the first li item, but the ul block disappears completely when i try to hover over any subitem except the first one. its... particularly odd. *Looks at Nikita and crosses fingers*